# What is the best way to generate and update charts from csv data in python

Tags: python

I have got a bunch of data in csv files, I am doing some computation on this data and displaying charts, right now this is all matplotlib and not interactive at all, just takes whatever command line arguments I feed it .

I want I to be able to change some values and for the chart to redraw, I was thinking this might be better as a web app so I wouldn`t have to go down the Pyside route .

Also, I'm guessing that I should consolidate all my csv data into one sqlite3 database .

Should I look at Django for that kind of functionality ? or maybe some other package would be better suited ( flask with pygooglechart maybe ? ) .

Would love to hear your suggestions .

thank you

Comment: What is your use case? Stuff like "a bunch of data" "some computation" don't help in suggesting solutions. Not to mention this type of question will quickly get closed since its asking for people's opinions and not dealing with a concrete programming problem. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more.

Comment: just trying to get a feel of what is available in python for displaying charts in the browser .

Comment: the data is timedata with values, nothing very interesting there, I derive probabilities from there, but I thought that was outside the scope of my question .

Comment: you could give flask or django with d3.js a try. if you are not familiar with them it's probably too much to learn for "only" displaying charts - but in the end - d3 is really good and I can recommend it. http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display charts in browser easily you could use Google Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: Actually wouldn't use any of the Google APIs if you don't absolutely have to. While they are truly fantastic, they change more frequently than I buy shoes. If you want something that's going to last, it would be through one of the open source javascript frameworks, like D3 for example. IIRC, some of these can even load from csv and do calcs.